# ViewController.Type does not have a member names 'answerOne' - SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am making a swift app. It is a trivia app for fun and I have run into an issue that I havent seen before. (I am new to swift and ios development errors)

```
import UIKit

class TriviaViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var myQuestionCounter: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var myQuestion: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var firstAnswer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var secondAnswer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var thirdAnswer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var fourthAnswer: UIButton!



var timer = NSTimer() //TO-DO
var count = 0
var questionCounter = 0

var firstQuestion = "What was the first planet to be discovered using the telescope, in 1781?"
var answerOne = "Mercury"
var answerTwo = "Uranus"
var answerThree = "Venus"
var answerFour = "Jupiter"

var firstCorrectAnswer = 2

//This next line gives the ERROR
let questionOneArray = [answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour, firstCorrectAnswer]

}
```

When I declare the "questionOneArray", it says "TriviaViewController does not have a member named 'answerOne'"

Please explain to me what this error is and how I can fix it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1** : Your code is not inside a method, you have to wrap it inside the method. Check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27220598/1866077)

**Solution 2** : Keep your `questions and answers` inside `struct` and access them, if you don't want to wrap it inside a function.

```
struct firstQuestion {
    static var question = "What was the first planet to be discovered using the telescope, in 1781?"
    static var answerOne = "Mercury"
    static var answerTwo = "Uranus"
    static var answerThree = "Venus"
    static var answerFour = "Jupiter"
    static var correctAnswer = "Correct Answer"
}

var questionOneArray = [firstQuestion.answerOne, firstQuestion.answerTwo, firstQuestion.answerThree, firstQuestion.answerFour, firstQuestion.correctAnswer]
```